# Error when importing library in Typescript for static website

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

I'm new to the Typescript world and I'm facing an issue.
I'm trying to create a script to access firebase database functions, but when compiling the script I'm running into :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` if I use `"module": "commonjs"` in my `tsconfig.json`

or

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` if I use `"module": "es6"`

In the second case, I can remove those three lines from the generated `index.js` file and everything is working properly :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/auth";
```

My question is, how can I use those external libraries in my typescript code, link them in my html without having those import in the compiled js file ?

Edit : Here's my ts file :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/database"
import "firebase/auth"

class FbManager {
    private static instance: FbManager;
    
    firebaseConfig: object;

    private constructor() {
        this.firebaseConfig = {
            ...
          };
        
        firebase.initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            console.log("AUTH STATE CHANGED");
            if (user) {      
              console.log("LOGGED IN USER " + user.uid);
              console.log(user);
            } else {
              console.log("SIGN OUT");
            }
          });
     }

    public static getInstance(): FbManager {
        if (!FbManager.instance) {
            FbManager.instance = new FbManager();
        }

        return FbManager.instance;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in your repo type `tsc --init` after that TS config file will be generated.

Go to this file and uncomment `outDir` and after semicolon write e.g. `"./build"`. Whole line will look like this `"outDir": "./build"`

Next thing you can do is to go to your `package.json` and in `scripts` write `build: tsc`. You'll be able to run npm command which will build your `.ts` files in `build` directory.

Comment: I have no trouble compiling my ts file with tsc, this is not the problem. My trouble is that the output js file doesn't work properly with my index.html